# Добавление UIStepper через код и верстка интерфейса Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

Верстаю интерфейс через код и столкнулся с проблемой, если добавить UIStepper в Main.storyboard и потом перетащить в код, создав @IBOutlet, то после этого я могу получить доступ к свойству stepper.frame.width, для того чтоб установить констрейнты или присвоить например ширину stepper какой-нибудь кнопке, но если я добавляю stepper через код (как на картинке), создав "var stepper: UIStepper!", то как можно получить ширину stepper, для использования ее в дальнейшем?

[image: UIStepper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь два вопроса в одном ) Во-первых, вы не создаете объект строчкой `var stepper: UIStepper!` а объявляете переменную. О чем нам и говорит ошибка на экране - система ожидает какой-то ненулевой объект, а он равен nil. То есть перед использованием вам надо его создать, примерно вот так:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stepper = UIStepper()
    stepper.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - stepper.frame.width, y: view.frame.midY, width: stepper.frame.width, height: stepper.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(stepper)
}
```

Comment: Да вы правы, я неверно выразился, я объявляю переменную)

Comment: Но потом, я не хочу менять размер stepper, на сколько я понимаю, у него есть стандартные размеры, и вот я хочу получить доступ к ним. Например я хочу установить и закрепить stepper через код в правой части экрана, вот пример кода, он конечно выдаст ошибку, но для понимания моей идеи я думаю он подойдет  " stepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width - stepper.frame.width, y: view.frame.midY, width: 0, height: 0)) "

Comment: Поправил, у меня все работает!

Comment: Да! "stepper = UIStepper()" это то, чего мне не хватало, вроде очевидно сейчас, но сразу я не подумал об этом. Спасибо!